# Can an administrator see what I do in a remote desktop environment?

Tags: security, remote-desktop

Can an administrator see what I do in a remote desktop environment? 
Is it possible at all, does it depend on certain programs?

Answer (score 4):

Potentially. Remote Desktop Services has a built in "shadow" feature, which allows an administrator to monitor your session in real-time without prompting for permission (if configured that way).

In addition to that, they may have any one of a number of other monitoring tools enabled on the infrastructure that do clandestine screen recording.